# solve the following for limit tending to infinity (without the use of L'Hospital's Rule)

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Limit is tending to infinity (remember without  L'Hospital's Rule)

> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\left[\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}\right]^2$$

Comment: L'hospital is not for that kind of case I think. The rule is for $p(x)/q(x)$ type where $p$ and $q$ both converge or to zero or to infinity

Comment: @RafaelWagner I want the solution without  L'Hospital's Rule

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left[\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2-1}\right]^2$$

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2-1}
&=(\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2-1})\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
&=\dfrac{x^2+1 - (x^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
&=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}\\
\text{so}\\
x\left[\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2-1}\right]^2
&=x\left(\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1}}\right)^2\\
&=\dfrac{4x}{(\sqrt{x^2+1} + \sqrt{x^2-1})^2}\\
&=\dfrac{4x}{(x(\sqrt{1+1/x^2} + \sqrt{1-1/x^2}))^2}\\
&=\dfrac{4}{x(\sqrt{1+1/x^2} + \sqrt{1-1/x^2})^2}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

If it had
$x^2\left[\sqrt{x^2+1} - \sqrt{x^2-1}\right]^2
$,
the limit would be $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
Expand the square to get
$$
(x^2+1) + (x^2-1) - 2\sqrt{(x^2+1)(x^2-1)}
 = 2x^2 - 2 \sqrt{x^4-1}
$$
and now expand the root into Taylor series.

Comment: Instead of Taylor series, you could also multiplicate by the "conjugate" ...